# The method getSupportLoaderManager() is undefined for the type Activity

Tags: android, android-listfragment, android-loadermanager

I'm getting "The method getSupportLoaderManager() is undefined for the type Activity" when using getSupportLoaderManager() inside a List Fragment. Do you have any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks!

The ListActivity is defined as :

```
public class SelfieListActivity extends FragmentActivity implements SelfieListFragment.Callbacks{...}
```

And the ListFragment is defined as :

```
public class SelfieListFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{...}
```

The line is inside the ListFragment and it's defined as :

```
    getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(_ID, null, this);
```

Thanks in advance!.
Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 1):

You may be inheriting from `android.app.ListFragment` instead of `android.support.v4.app.ListFragment`.

Comment: That fixed the issue but created a new one.
Now it gives me a Cannont cast Fragment on SelfieList Fragment on the following > ((SelfieListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.selfie_list)).setActivateOnItemClick(true);

Comment: @KillDash9: Change `getFragmentManager()` to `getSupportFragmentManager()`. You need to be *consistent* in your use of fragment implementation, not try to mix and match native fragments and the `support.v4` fragments backport.